# Adjusting HTML form value after navigating to a different page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function adjustform(){
            window.location = 'pagewithforms.html';
            ddl = document.getElementById("test");
            ddl.value = 3; 
            }
```

That is my code so far, I basically want an onClick function to change the values of a drop down on another page. Below is my html.

```
<a href="#" onClick="adjustform()">
      <p>click this link to go to 'pagewithforms.html' and change the dropdown with id 'test' to value 3</a>
```

However after the window.location runs in the function, the script seems to stop and will not change the value of the form once relocated. Any suggestions?

Comment: You misunderstood some basic principles of webpages, i guess. where is the point in changing a page that is going to be disappearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is normal, you're replacing the page entirly and thus the old page and scripts are no longer there :

You can use jQuery however to solve your problem:

```
$.load('pagewithforms.html', function () {
    $('#test').val(3);
}
```

This will load your page and the callback will set the value of the element 'test' to three.

Comment: How would I assign this to an onClick attribute? (Novice)

Comment: wrap a function around it, and call that function onclick :


 

function clicked() {
$.load('pagewithforms.html', function () {
    $('#test').val(3);
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Once you change the windows location the browsers loads a new page, and all javascript on the old page is lost as javascript in a browser enviroment has no concept of state, it starts anew on every pageload.